# walware in frontpage

Tags: magento-1.9

This code is found in my frontpage. Where to go to remove this crap?

:root topadblock, :root input[onclick^="window.open('http://www.FriendlyDuck.com/"], :root img[alt^="Fuckbook"], :root iframe[src^="http://static.mozo.com.au/strips/"], :root iframe[src^="http://cdn2.adexprt.com/"], :root iframe[id^="google_ads_iframe"], :root header#hdr + #main > div[data-hveid],

etc etc

Answer (score 1):

I would start by checking the following things:

1. core_config_data table. A lot of times malware is included in design area, footer, miscellaneous html, etc.. You can do this by running this query:
   `select * from core_config_data where value like "&iframe&";` check for the inserted code
2. CMS blocks and pages - check any recently edited content
3. check any recently edited files on the server - the attacker may have already compromised your server. You can do this by running this in the root of your server:`find . -type f -mtime -7 -name "*.php"` check for all file types
4. make sure there are no backdoors left on the server. Run a malware scan to be sure.
5. I suggest changing all passwords for users - magento, ssh, ftp, mysql, etc..

There is a lot more to do but these are the most critical things.

If you are not sure how to do these things then I would suggest you find someone. Being hacked is no joke and should be handled with respect. Both shop owner and customers are affected here.

Answer (score 0):

Check the field Miscellaneous Scripts from

System->Configuration->Design->Head

Here scripts will be added before the tag and you can set different scripts per website or even store views.

Check different store scopes. Check for white space before to mask existence.

If it is there once removed don't forget to clear your Magento cache: System > Cache Management > Flush Magento Cache

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself but found it could be the built in adblocker in Opera. When I turned the add blocker off the code went away.

Answer (score 0):

its a adblocker script, it has nothing to do with your code, simply turn off addblocker on your browser to remove this.